# watson-knowledge-studio Can Watson Knowledge Studio from IBM be installed locally? Or is it a Cloud only offering?

Tags: ibm-watson

I am interested in using WKS but have lots of documents that cannot be put up on a "cloud".   Can WKS be used locally?  If not, is anyone aware of a group annotation tool that is?

Answer (score 0):

Watson Knowledge Studio is a Cloud only offering. It is hosted in US South, Germany, Sydney and US East.

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/resources/services_region.html#services_region